# How to get access token using ASP.NET OWIN and Web Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, owin

I am using OWIN and Web Forms in ASP.NET.  I am using the .NET Framework 4.6.1 (not .NET Core).  Now I need to be able to get the Access Token and Refresh Token.

How do I actually get those values?  The API is complicated and not clear how to do this.

This is via standard OWIN from the ASP.NET template; i.e.:

```
app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
{
    ClientId = "...",
    ClientSecret = "..."
});
```

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post the code that you tried

Comment: Added the code (it's standard from the template)

Comment: when you called this code, what happened?

Comment: It works, I just can't get the Access_Token because I can't find the place in .NET where this is exposed

Comment: It works? So it calls back against your `redirect_uri` with an authorisation code? Then you call `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token` with that code? Then you get a JSON result? I am basically leading you through the documentation that the answer links to below. Going by the code you have posted and your explanation, it seems to me you haven't really tried anything.

Comment: PS the doco below is for google OAuth which may or may not be what you are using. Can you confirm whether you are using google for your identity provider or are you using Azure AD (Organizational accounts) ? Here's the Azure AD link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code

Comment: It works, I just can't retreive the Access_Token.  I'm using OWIN (MS OAuth) + Google as the identity provider

Comment: You already said you "can't get the access" token. Is it because the code you tried gave an empty result, gave an error, or you don't know what code to write? Please look at my last comment and indicate which parts of the process are functioning for you. Do you have JSON result?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the compete [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer) that might be helpful in generating Client ID and Secret in order to integrate a .Net application with Google OAuth 2.0.

Comment: Thanks but that is actually not the question.  The client ID and secret are not the access token.  The access token is a per-user transient authorization token.